# [UPDATED]How to save data on Microsoft SQL server after update through HTTP POST Flutter

Tags: sql-server, flutter, dart

Every time I click the "True" button it sends values "True" to SQL server database and updates the new value, after that it's immediately reset to  "False". How do I fix this??

[UPDATED]Here's my script MSSQL server update data :

```cs
USE [dieukhien]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[uodateTrangThaiAppByidMach]    Script Date: Tue 20 06 09 12:40:35 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[uodateTrangThaiAppByidMach]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @id_mach_dien nvarchar(10) = null,
    @trang_thaiapp bit,
    @giatri_app bit
AS
BEGIN

   update datas set trang_thai_app= @trang_thaiapp, giatri_app=@giatri_app  where id_mach_dien=@id_mach_dien

END
```

main.dart

```
Future<UserModel> createUser(String id, bool trangthaiapp, bool giatriapp) async {

    final response = await http.post(apiUrl, headers: headers,
        body: json.encode({
            "id_machdien": id,
             "trang_thaiapp": trangthaiapp,
             "giatri_app:": giatriapp,
        })
    );

    if(response.statusCode == 200) {
        final String responseString = response.body;

        return userModelFromJson(responseString);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

    UserModel _user;

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {

        return MaterialApp (
            home: Scaffold (
                appBar: AppBar (
                    title: Text(widget.title),
                ),
                body:Center (
                    child: Column (
                        children: <Widget> [ 
                            RaisedButton (
                                onPressed: () async {
                                    final String id = "333";
                                    final bool trangthaiapp = true;
                                    final bool giatriapp= true;
                                    final UserModel user = await createUser(
                                        id, trangthaiapp, giatriapp);

                                    setState(() { _user = user; });
                                },
                            ),
                            RaisedButton (
                                onPressed: () async {
                                    final String id = "333";
                                    final bool trangthaiapp = false;
                                    final bool giatriapp= false;
                                    final UserModel user = await createUser(
                                        id, trangthaiapp, giatriapp);
                                    setState(() { _user = user; });
                                },
                            ),
                        ],
                    ),
                ),
            )
        );
    }
}
```

As for class `user_model.dart`

```
import 'dart:convert';

UserModel userModelFromJson(String str) => UserModel.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String userModelToJson(UserModel data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class UserModel {
    String id;
    String trangthaiapp;
    String giatriapp;

    UserModel({
        this.id,
        this.trangthaiapp,
        this.giatriapp,
    });

    factory UserModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
        var userModel = UserModel (
            id: json["id_machdien"],
            trangthaiapp: json["trang_thaiapp"],
            giatriapp: json["giatri_app"],
        );
        return userModel;
    }

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id_machdien": id,
         "trang_thaiapp": trangthaiapp,
         "giatri_app": giatriapp,
    };
}
```

Here's my API code project:

```cs
// ValuesController.cs

using API.IOT.Models;
using BasicAuthentication;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Charts;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace API.IOT.Controllers {
    public class ValuesController : ApiController {
        // GET api/values
        public object Get(MachDien value) {
            using (dieukhienEntities db = new dieukhienEntities()) {
                //return db.getDataByidMach(value.id_machdien).ToString();
                var entity = db.getDataByidMach(value.id_machdien).FirstOrDefault();
                return entity;
            }
        }
        // POST api/values
        [BasicAuthentication]
        public object Post(MachDien value) {
            dieukhienEntities db = new dieukhienEntities();

            int save = db.uodateTrangThaiBorByidMach(value.id_machdien,value.trang_thai,value.giatri_bor);

            int saveapp = db.uodateTrangThaiAppByidMach(value.id_machdien,value.trang_thaiapp,value.giatri_ap);

            getDataByidMach_Result item = db.getDataByidMach(value.id_machdien).FirstOrDefault();

            return value;
        }
    }
}
```

And here's my Models.cs:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace API.IOT.Models {
    public class MachDien {
        public string id_machdien { get; set; }
        public bool trang_thai { get; set; }
        public bool trang_thaiapp { get; set; }
        public bool giatri_app { get; set; }
        public bool giatri_bor { get; set; }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Hi,
Welcome to Stack Overflow, the problem could be in your API project or in the response that you are receiving, Please share the JSON response that you are receiving from the API. Also it will be helpful if you can post the API code in which you are updating the MSSQL table

Comment: Hi, i just updated my API in my post, please check!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are returning the same object passed into the API, are you setting the boolean fields to true in API, then you need either return the changed object or set the boolean fields to true in your returning object.

```
[BasicAuthentication]
public object Post(MachDien value)
{
    dieukhienEntities db = new dieukhienEntities();
    int save = db.uodateTrangThaiBorByidMach(value.id_machdien,value.trang_thai,value.giatri_bor);

    int saveapp = db.uodateTrangThaiAppByidMach(value.id_machdien,value.trang_thaiapp,value.giatri_app);

    getDataByidMach_Result item = db.getDataByidMach(value.id_machdien).FirstOrDefault();

    value.giatri_app = true; //set the field (s) you want to return true as value here
    return value; // here you are sending the same object which you are received, no modifications done.
}
```

Comment: So how can i fix this "return value;" line. Can you help me?

Comment: can you please write print(responseString) after final String responseString = response.body;; and paste the output here?

Comment: Output: I/flutter (17699): {"id_machdien":"333","trang_thai":false,"trang_thaiapp":false,"giatri_app":false,"giatri_bor":false}
I/flutter (17699): 200

THANK YOU SO MUCH. I found out print(responseString) will save data on SQL server, but when i use print(response.body) it didn't save data on SQL

Comment: no, print is used to log the output to console, i wanted to know whether you did the changes i mentioned and you are still returning the same object, so the changed didn't came

Comment: my api code didn't changes anything. I only add your print(responseString) after final String responseString = response.body; and it's solved my problem.